# Whats an efficient, correct way of using monk / mongo in express middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, monk

I have a web app under development. I found [CW Buechler's tutorial](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2014/restful-web-app-node-express-mongodb/) on how to make a simple one very useful but have a couple of niggling worries that I'd like to know whether they're real issues, or things I can ignore.

The way I connect my routes to my database is straight from the tutorials.

in app.js, this code instantiates the database, and attaches a reference to it to every req object that flows thru the middleware.

```
// wire up the database
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('monk')('localhost:27017/StarChamber');

----------8<-------

// Make our db accessible to our router
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    req.db = db;
    next();
});
```

And in the middleware it get used like this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('myCollection');
    // do stuff to produce results
    res.json (results);
});
```

So, to my niggling worries:

1. Passing the db to the routes by attaching it to the req is pretty convenient, but does it impact performance? Would it be better to have a reference to it in my router file that I could just use? What's the code to do this?
2. Is it good practice to drop the collection after its been used? The Tutorial doesn't do so, but a `collection.drop()` call before exiting the route handler looks beneficial, otherwise I think I'll just rack up lots of open connections with the db.

Thanks as ever!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, it won't impact performance. It's a convenient method to pass a reference to `db` around, but with Monk it doesn't seem to be especially necessary. See below for an alternative setup.
2. You are confusing `collections` with `connections`. The former are the MongoDB-equivalent of "tables" in SQL, so dropping them doesn't seem to make sense since that would basically throw away all the data in your database table. As for connections: through various layers of indirection, Monk seems to be using the official MongoDB Node driver, which handles connections itself (by means of a connection pool). So there's no need to handle it yourself.

For an alternative way of passing the Monk database handle around: you can place it in a separate module:

```
// database.js
module.exports = require('monk')('localhost:27017/StarChamber');
```

And in each module where you require the handle, you can import it:

```
var db = require('./database');
```